# How can I prove that the zeroes of $f(z)=1+1/2^z$ have no real part?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I want to prove that the zeroes of the function $f(z)=1+1/2^{z}$ have no real part. Is the following correct?

$f(z)=0$ so $2^{z} = -1$ and $-1=e^{i\pi}$ so $e^{i\pi} = e^{z\ln2}$ therefore $z= i\pi/(\ln2)$ which has no real part. Is the proof correct? If not, what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is globally correct, except that there are infinitely many roots $z$ to this equation, that differ by a multiple of $2i\pi$.